# My DAC files extracted from SSMS have a file type in Spanish

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server-2008, ssms-2012, dac

I do a lot of schema compares in my work. I've started extracting DAC files from the databases using Tasks --> Extract Data-tier Applications in SSMS, then doing the schema-compare in Visual Studio. That part works great! Much better that saving and restoring whole databases to my desktop.

The problem, if you can call it that, is that the file type of the extracted .DAC file is in Spanish. ***Archivo de paquete DAC de Microsoft SQL Server*** (DAC package file of Microsoft SQL Server). The contextual menu on these files has Desempaquetar (unpack) as the first entry, though the rest of the menu is in English.

Has anyone else ever had that happen?

P.S. Windows Server 2008 R2 is the OS for the server I'm doing the extractions on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a known issue with one particular version of the DacFramework.msi that installs the Dac unpack tool. You should be fine installing [a more recent version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39976) of the DAC framework for SQL Server 2012 - it'll fix this issue for you.